# How to get WebRTC experimentals stats

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to get some statistics about a WebRTC live stream.

On `chrome://webrtc-internals` I am able to see some statistics marked **experimental** (with a `*`), that I can not find using `getStats` method.
That includes `freezeCount`, `pauseCount`, `totalFreezesDuration`, `totalPausesDuration`, `totalFramesDuration`, `sumOfSquaredFramesDuration`

**Do you know how to get those statistics using JavaScript ?**

---

Note: I found this [W3 draft of a potential specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-provisional-stats/) that describe those statistics, but cannot find any example on the web.

Note: I am using *Google Chrome*

Note: According to [this commit](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src.git/+/0237106559e63aea6d1ef4b11b64a32413564cdd), those metrics where introduce in February 2019 so quite long ago...

Comment: Is [this blog post](https://antmedia.io/an-overview-webrtc-statistics/) what you are looking for?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. As those are only mentioned in that draft, I'd assume it's currently not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values are not available to Javascript/getStats because they're not standardized. If you consider them useful, file an issue on https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-provisional-stats and provide a compelling use-case.